# how to pass string containing newline to python in php

Tags: php, python

I have the following line of code in php that I m using to execute the python screen. and it takes in text from a html textarea which will contain newline characters

```
$string = $_POST['textarea']; // e.g. "String 1\n string 2\n"
$command = escapeshellcmd("python script.py -c \"$string\"");
```

when the script.py is executed, only "String 1" is received by the python script as arg. May I ask is there any native way for me to get the string passed?

If you feel that this is a duplicated question, please let me know where I can find this answer. I have been searching it all over stackoverflow.

Comment: inside  your script.py `sys.argv[1] = sys.argv[1].rstrip()`

Comment: nope that will not work. Im trying to pass strings containing newline. Im not trying to trim my string

Comment: sys.argv[1] = sys.argv[1].split("\n") got a list inside `sys.argv[1]`

Comment: the issue now is that it is not even being captured by sys.argv. when i print out argv[1], only String 1 is found

Comment: ok, change `local_var = sys.argv[1].split("\n")` incoming  type maybe not string.

Comment: if "string 1\nstring 2\n" is passed successfully to the command without eacaping will that run properly?

Comment: How to convert  "string 1\nstring 2\n" to a list or multi elements object ? @CapitalC

Comment: He say `i push string` but not sure ! First `\n` run python script, others go to garbage !

Comment: if the Python script is able to split the arguments by "\n" then you may try replacing "\n" in $string to "\\n" so that the delimiter become "\n" after escaping.

Comment: I would like to test this out. how do I print out the argument list in Python (I don't know this language :P)?

Comment: This is not `python` relevances ! Check this : http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php and `Terminal / CMD` always grab `\n` characters.

Comment: im trying to execute python script in the shell using php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a way to do this.

In the php file, replace all the newline with '\n' before calling escapeshellcmd

```
$string = trim(preg_replace('/[\r\n]+/', '\n', $_POST['textarea']));

// For a string like:
// abcd
// defg
// will become
// abde\\ndefg
```

Since the newline char '\n' has been escaped by php escapeshellcmd with the prepended slash. the shell will be able to process the string and python will receive **abde\ndefg** as one of the arguments.
Next in the python code, we simply have to undo the escape using the code below

```
arg = sys.argv[1].decode('string_escape')
```

I hope the above solution will be able to help those who are facing the similar issue as me. =)